# css @font-face Steelfish not working on IE 7 and 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I have a problem, I've implemented a css `@font-face` on my css, and it's ok in the Internet Explorer 9, FireFox and Chrome, but when I access my website with Internet Explorer 7 and Internet Explorer 8 it's not working. Look at my code below, someone has any suggestion code for me?

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Steelfish";
  src: url('../fonts/steelfish/steelfish_eb-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/steelfish/steelfish_eb-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../fonts/steelfish/steelfish_eb-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: 800;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: "Steelfish";
  src: url('../fonts/steelfish/steelfish_bd-webfont.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/steelfish/steelfish_bd-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot'), url('../fonts/steelfish/steelfish_bd-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: bold;}
```

Comment: Reno Yeo,how can i to use zoom:1 with @font-face ? it's only put it inside {} ?

Comment: Where does the font come from, how did you generate the different font files, and where can we test the code in action (with a URL)?

Comment: no, you put zoom:1 in the areas that contain the text - like body {font-family:yourfont; zoom:1;}